# Can we find a more intuitive way to make http links in comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

I find myself forgetting how to make links in comments and one way to save my time had been if these two sequences were intrepreted the same

`[a gae task](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) or a [mapreduce job](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/).`

`(https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/)[a gae task] or a (https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/)[mapreduce job].`

..so that the order does not matter of the components. It could also be done so that it is indifferent between `(` and `[` so that all 4 possible combinations are "legal" ways to link and none of them become junk when submitting the comment.

It would be easier to not have to remember or check for the syntax. Or even make the comment field with icon for links like in the question and answer field. Could it be done? If not, why not?

Comment: I ran into this same frustration, but it's really just something you get used to over time, like most of Markdown.

Comment: Just click the "help" link next to the comment box when writing one for a syntax  reminder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Link syntax is [part of the Markdown Specification](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link).  Markdown is what SE uses to provide special formatting in the editor.  In theory, that means once you memorize the syntax for SE, it should work anywhere else Markdown formatting is being used.

There are special cases (like parentheses or brackets that are part of the actual link or description) that are handled automatically.

Answer (score 4):

By the examples you give, maybe the following [browser bookmarklet](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-bookmarklets-the-right-way--net-18154) can help. It grabs the current page title and URL and opens a dialog with a markdown link so we can copy `[page-title](page-url)`:

[image]

***Bookmarklet:***

```javascript
javascript:(function(){ var result='['+document.title+']('+document.URL+')'; window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", result); })();
```

***Favicon:***

Bookmarklets cannot have favicons, but a nice workaround is to use an [Unicode symbol](http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/) as the name.

[image: unicode title] <sup>[*h/t: Stefano*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521040/how-to-have-favicon-icon-set-when-bookmarklet-dragged-to-toolbar/19128254#19128254)</sup>

<sub>*Related [Add markdown quick-links to the share dialog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239362/185667)*</sub>

Comment: This bookmarklet also copies the site name and the main tag in the link text, so you have to remove those afterwards.